# Return ternary operator in JavaScript reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof, reduce

I have a data structure like this:

```
var example = [
    { name: "item1", year: 2013, value: 100 },
    { name: "item1", year: 2012, value:  97 },
    { name: "item3", year: 2013, value:  93 },
    { name: "item3", year: 2012, value:  91 },
    { name: "item2", year: 2012, value:  -6 },
    { name: "item2", year: 2011, value:  -5 },
    { name: "item4", year: 2012, value: -36 },
    { name: "item3", year: 2011, value:  93 },
    { name: "item4", year: 2013, value: -35 },
    { name: "item1", year: 2011, value:  98 },
    { name: "item2", year: 2013, value:  -7 },
    { name: "item4", year: 2011, value: -37 },
    { name: "item5", year: 2013, value:  58 },
    { name: "item5", year: 2012, value:  55 },
    { name: "item5", year: 2011, value:  54 }
];
```

I am using this function to get an array of single elements:

```
example.reduce(function (prev, curr) {
    if (prev.indexOf(curr.name) === -1) prev.push(curr.name);
    return prev;
}, []);
```

While this works, I try to use a ternary operator for readability like this:

```
example.reduce(function (prev, curr) {
    return prev.indexOf(curr.name) === -1 ? prev.push(curr.name) : prev;
}, []);
```

and I get the following error in Chrome:

```
Uncaught TypeError: prev.indexOf is not a function
    at <anonymous>:3:13
    at Array.reduce (native)
    at <anonymous>:2:9
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:895:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:828:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:694:21)
```

Why is that?

Comment: That is because `push` function doesn't return the same array.

Comment: That's because [`.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) doesn't return an array. It returns the new length of the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it is because calling [.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) will return the new length of the array which is a number, so the second call `prev` will be a number(1) which don't have the push method.

> Returns
>
> The new length property of the object upon which the method was
>   called.

So using the `if` condition will be better in your case.

If you want to still use the ternary operator, you can use a hacky solution like

```
var b = example.reduce(function (prev, curr) {
    return prev.indexOf(curr['name']) === -1 ? prev.push(curr['name']) && prev : prev;
}, []);
```

Comment: You can make your solution less hacky. See my answer above.

Answer (score 2):

Replace your ternary operator with `&&` and `,` instead of `?` and `:` as follows:

```
example.reduce(function (prev, curr) {
    return prev.indexOf(curr.name) < 0 && prev.push(curr.name), prev;
}, []);
```

In this case, instead of using the ternary operator we use logical AND to test whether `prev.indexOf(curr.name) < 0` and if so then we do `prev.push(curr.name)`. However, we always return `prev` because of the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).

As I mentioned in my comment, your code doesn't work because [`.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) doesn't return the original array. It returns the new length of the array. You could replace `.push` with [`.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/concat) but it would be very inefficient. The method I described above is better.

Comment: Thanks, although your answer is valid and i learned more on the comma operator, for readability I prefer to use the ternary operator. Will try to do a jsperf to see which one is best performing and will choose accordingly.